# (Android) How to catch application main thread termination (if it is put in backround)

Tags: java, android, singleton

Well, in my Android application I have few singleton objects that processes some whole-application needs (like server request, data downloading, in-application log-collectors and some other needs).

All of these singleton objects have their own state and store some whole-application data (like opened user sessions on server or others). Most of activities that shows on screen uses singletons' data during (re)creating their view. In other hands, activities are like "foreground/views" and singleton objects are like "background".

Sometimes during application using, user switches to homescreen or other application. 
Some time after last activity hides from screen, we have the application main thread running, and all singleton objects living in memory and working in that thread.

The last one is that I want - to store all singleton objects in "background" as long as it is possible. (there are few reasons for it like "*initialising all of them could takes a time*" (I do not want start reinitialisation, if user comes back to application in nearest time) or "*some network functions needs to be finalised correctly with notifications to server* "... )

But - there some time becomes, when android decides, that it is good time to kill all process that have no shown activities. For free some memory, it may be, or due a bad mood. 
And it destroys main application process with all my singleton objects.

Ans here is my issue: I need to handle that moment -- for saving internal state of my singleton objects or just for making log note like '*I was closed*' -- and I don`t know how to do it. 
(for example, .finalize() is not called in that scenario).

**What is the best way to handle application singleton-objects` destroy (not activity!).**

ps:thanks, and sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 2):

Extend [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and override its event handlers. Specifically, there's onTrimMemory and onLowMemory should warn you it's about time to clean up.

That said, over-use of singletons seems to indicate a bad design. You should perhaps be using a Service or storing state in a database if it's not used often but needs to persist.

Comment: I don't think we can assume that if the OS kills the app is always due to low memory. Even if it were, it is the kind of behaviour that is OS-version dependent.

Comment: I'm with Dave on this one. I don't think that OP is misusing singleton. I have a feeling that services would be better for server request, data downloading and log-collectors.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of persisting data is probably Shared Preferences.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Now you are talking about having the singletons in memory as long as possible even when there are no activities around. That is undesirable and I think it is not possible unless you resort to "clever" tricks you might think work but eventually wont. Hey, you can't even guarantee your activities are not going to be killed by the OS. You could certainly persist the singletons state using any persistence mechanism (preferences, files, DB, etc), but that won't be fast. You will always have a performance penalty in reading from persistence or fetching from the net.